# React Router: how to have the same route in multiple conditions? Breaking my application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

I am trying to use both Redux state management, and React Router, but am having an issue that is driving me nuts and cannot find a solution on the web.

I have a redux state called user, that stores the information of a logged in user. Upon logging in, with the reducer `loginUser`, the state updates with the users information, and stores it into local storage. My `useEffect()` in App.js checks if there is a user stored in local storage, and if so logins in the user with `loginUser`.

App.js has two potential renders, one where there isn't a user found in the state with `useSelector`, and one where there is.

Whenever I go straight to `/player/admin` for example, my console logs throughout the components as shown below go haywire.

```
app component
VM643:236 app component
Player.js:8 player component
VM643:236 player component
Player.js:12 inside player effect
Player.js:12 inside player effect
App.js:16 app component
VM643:236 app component
Player.js:8 player component
VM643:236 player component
Player.js:12 inside player effect
Player.js:12 inside player effect
```

It seems as if when the user is logged in, it first renders the Route in the return statement when there is no user, and then once it verifies they are logged in, the Route in the return where there is a user calls it again. This cause `<Player>` to be rendered twice.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a work around to this? If I have a fetch api call inside my Player useffect, it would call it like more than twice, which is crazy. I have to declare the routes twice because if one has it and not the other, depending on whether a user is signed in and you go to a route it would give me a console error saying it does not exist.

```
// React 
import { useEffect } from 'react'

// Redux
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

// React Reducer
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import { loginUser, logoutUser } from './reducers/user';

// Components
import Login from './components/Login';
import Player from './components/Player';

function App() {
  console.log("app component")
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user)

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user= JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      dispatch(loginUser(user))
    }
  }, [])

  // User not logged in
  if (!user) { 
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login/>} />
        <Route path="/player/:username" element={<Player/>}/> 
      </Routes>
    )
  }
  
  // User logged in
  return (
    <div>
      <h1><button onClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())}>LOG OUT</button></h1>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<h1>HOME</h1>}/>
        <Route path="/" element={<h1>HOME</h1>} />
        <Route path="/player/:username" element={<Player/>}/> 
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Player component:

```
// React Router
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

// React
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Player = () => {
    console.log("player component")
    const urlParam = useParams().username

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("inside player effect")
    })
    return(<h1>player</h1>)
}
export default Player
```

Comment: Are you using react 18? Are you using StrictMode? Are you compiling in dev mode? See this discussion: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/35822

Comment: Yes to all of those, although removing strictmode doesnt seem to make a difference. it seems that having the routes in two different areas, depending if a user is logged in, makes the route recall the component

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to exclude tht problem. Because React18 changed that and *a lot* of people end up having surprises with double execution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use protected route. You can follow [Robin Wieruch's](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-private-routes/) guide